# Using functools.total_ordering for comparisons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code...

```
class BankAccount:
    """ Simple BankAccount class """

    def __init__(self, balance=0):
        """Initialize account with balance"""
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """Deposit amount to this account"""
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """Withdraw amount from this account"""
        self.balance -= amount

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Account with a balance of {}'.format(self.balance)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "BankAccount(balance={})".format(self.balance)

    def __bool__(self):
        if self.balance > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The code is basically a simple bank account simulator. I want to implement comparisons for BankAccount objects, such that instances can be compared based on their balance. I want to do this using functools.total_ordering. An expected output is below...

```
    account1 = BankAccount(100)
    account2 = BankAccount()
    account3 = BankAccount(100)
    account1 == account2
False
    account1 == account3
True
    account1 != account3
False
    account1 < account2
False
    account1 >= account2
True
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Did you read the [`@total_ordering` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)? Was there anything unclear, have you had trouble with a specific implementation?

Comment: Side note: `self.balance > 0` itself already produces `True` or `False`; the `if ...: return True`, `else: return False` is much more verbose than is needed. Just replace that all with `return self.balance > 0`, although `return bool(self.balance)` would also do.

Comment: I am confused about the  def _is_valid_operand portion of the code and whether my code above would need it.

Comment: The documentation there links on to the [comparison hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), which explain when to return `NotImplemented`. The `_is_valid_operand` method implements a form of deciding when to return `NotImplemented`. It's optional, not absolutely required for your case.

Comment: Your question would be much better received if you asked *in your question body itself* about this confusion.

Comment: If my solution resolved your issue mark it as correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to define at least one of the functions:

`__lt__(), __le__(), __gt__(), or __ge__()`
In addition, the class should supply an `__eq__()` method.

Then you use the decorator like so:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class BankAccount:
""" Simple BankAccount class """

   def __init__(self, balance=0):
    """Initialize account with balance"""
       self.balance = balance
   def __lt__(self, other):
       return self.balance  < other.balance 
   def __eq__(self,other):
       return self.balance == other.balance
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. So would I need to define all of the functions above? Or could I just define one of them and _eq_ and the code would be able to interpret the other functions on its own?

Comment: As I wrote at least one. So one or if you want to more. In your case one will suffice as in my example :)

Comment: Is there a reason there would be a name error for @total_ordering?

Comment: You need to import it first. I edited my example check it out